# Correctly deploying multiple sites in a single Azure role

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, configuration

I can successfully deploy multiple c# .NET 4.5 websites to a single Azure web role, but I want to know whether I it's the correct way to do it as the `physicalDirectory` attribute in the `.csdef` file points to the `\websiteX\bin\Release` directory of each website being deployed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="MyWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="WebsiteX" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebsiteX\bin\release">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="http" hostHeader="WebsiteX.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="WebsiteY" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebsiteY\bin\release">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="http" hostHeader="WebsiteY.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="http" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I have seen in posts like these : [Can you deploy multiple webapps on one Windows Azure instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542518/can-you-deploy-multiple-webapps-on-one-windows-azure-instance/5157809#5157809) / http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/02/running-multiple-websites-in-a-windows-azure-web-role that the `physicalDirectory` attribute points towards what looks like the root directory of the website to be deployed (just `\websiteX` where the `.csproj` file for that resides, if I'm not mistaken?)

However when I point the `.csdef` `physicalDirectory` to this location (`\websiteX`) and deploy to Azure, the process actually deploys everything in that directory. Every folder and file gets effectively copied as-is up to Azure.

Here is the `.csdef` that I would like to use as it seems cleaner and is used in many examples on the web. Note the lack of `\bin\release`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="MyWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="WebsiteX" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebsiteX">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="http" hostHeader="WebsiteX.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="WebsiteY" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebsiteY">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" endpointName="http" hostHeader="WebsiteY.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="http" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

What am I doing wrong so that I cannot use the second `.csdef` file ? Why does the deployment from the second `.csdef` deploy the whole project directory into Azure rather than just the website's binaries ? Is there something out-of-the-box that is missing, or are custom post-build scripts needed ?